# Using SaltStack to create VPC on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, saltstack, aws-cli

I am not sure if this is even possible as I have not found any documentation or information otherwise regarding how to do this: can SaltStack be used to configure and create new VPCs into a given region on AWS? If so can someone please point me in the right direction or give some info to get the ball rolling?

I have only recently begun working with SaltStack. Thus far I have manually created the VPC in one region and setup a Salt Master instance there to deploy, configure, and manage other EC2 minions within that VPC. What I am looking for is a way to use Salt to create a new VPC in a different region - regardless of whether the current Master is hosted on AWS or external network. If this isn't possible I suppose I can use the AWS CLI tools and some scripts to handle this aspect of the setup.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but am up against the same challenge. I have found that the tools exist to do what we need to do, but much of this stuff seems to be at the cutting edge, with the current saltstack develop branch being required. Have a look here at the doco: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.boto_vpc.html#salt.modules.boto_vpc.create

Answer (score 1):

As of salt-2015.8.0 salt now has a boto_vpc state for what you are trying to accomplish https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.boto_vpc.html